# I am asking it to recognise the characters present in the image and we are asking to it to read the content and to store the content in a variable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I have written this code:

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType; 

// class and method declaration omitted

File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
//store screenshot at a specidfied location
File targetFile=new File("C:\\Users\\Srujan\\eclipse-workspace\\Batch98Appium\\images\\kiran.png");
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile,targetFile );
System.out.println(targetFile.toString());

// URL url1 = new URL(targetFile.toString());  
Image image = ImageIO.read(targetFile);         

// we are asking it to recognize the characers present in the image and we are asking to it to read the contnet and to store the content in a variable
String s = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image);  

//below cmd is simply printing the information
System.out.println("Text From Image : \n"+ s);  

if (s.contains("Monitored switch is on")) {
    System.out.println("toastr verified successfully");
} else {
    System.out.println("toastr not verified successfully");
}
```

I added jars as Maven dependencies:

> Java OCR API  15.3.0.1
>
> java-client 6.1.0

The following compile error appears:

> String s = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image);
>
> OCR().Recog...OCR cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: What are the `import` statements of your class ?

Comment: import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

Comment: Maybe brackets needed around new ORC() eg. String s = (new OCR()).recog

Comment: None of your import statements imports an `OCR` class.

Comment: Added imports form the OP's comment. Formatted code

Comment: What is with the subject of your post? Please have a read through [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the import for `Ocr` class (note the lower case letter by the way). Add this near the top of your file:

```
 import com.asprise.ocr.Ocr;
```

And correct the name of the class in to `Ocr`.

Comment: thank you, Roman, but I am used that is import statement but methods undefined error displaying... String s = new Ocr().recognize(RenderedImage image, String recognizeType,String outputFormat,object propSpec);